# '" is not a valid floating point value

Tags: delphi

```
  Price:=StrToFloat(Sqls.TSQLs.Create.Get('SELECT Cost FROM TblRoom WHERE 
  RoomType="' + Room + '" AND HotelName = ' + QuotedStr(Hotel),'Cost'));
```

The `Sqls.TSQLs.Create.Get` is a function I created to extract a value from the data base.NOTE its in a unit

```
function TSQLs.Get(SQL: string; value: string): string;
begin
with Databasehub.DataModule1 do
begin
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(SQL);
ADOQuery1.Open;
if (ADOQuery1.RecordCount = 1) then
begin
Result := ADOQuery1.FieldByName(value).AsString;
end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: please add the code in onshow event of form5

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: TSQLs.Get function returns empty string that called from onshow evetn of form5.

Comment: @sddk that's the error. I took it out and it worked. How can I fix it?

Comment: As the message clearly says, `StrToFloat()` can't convert an empty string. If an empty string is a valid value and should be converted to 0, use `StrToFloatDef()` instead. If it shouldn't happen, then just debug your code and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer should check if the value can be used to calculate price:

```
tmpStr := Sqls.TSQLs.Create.Get('SELECT Cost FROM TblRoom WHERE RoomType="' + Room + '" AND HotelName = ' + QuotedStr(Hotel),'Cost');
if not TryStrToFloat(tmpStr, Price) then
  Begin
    ShowMessage('be sure that the value exists, window will be closed!');
    Exit;
  End;
```

Also use sql parameters instead of inserting variables into string.

Comment: I'm only getting an error :overload version of TryStrToFloat

Comment: what is the type of Price?

Comment: Price type is real

Comment: Real type is an alias to Double, please try it by changing it's type to double. And also read some documents about floating points and use currency for price http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Currency

Comment: No, nothing to do with real or double. Just an older version of Delphi.

Answer (score -1):

Cost is probably a null value or empty string in the database. If you are using ADO then the DB is probably Sql Server. Use StrToFloatDef to identify these:

```
Price:= StrToFloatDef(Sqls.TSQLs.Create.Get('SELECT Cost FROM TblRoom WHERE 
RoomType="' + Room + '" AND HotelName = ' + QuotedStr(Hotel),'Cost'), 1000000.00);
```

Any time it can't do the conversion it will display 1000000.00, making it obvious that there is an issue - unless hotels really are a million a night.

Comment: adding default value can not be a solution. dev should check the value and warn the user about missing values.